# How do you add a custom share link to a FBML page on facebook?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'd simply like to make an image-click in my FBML page to trigger facebook's ajax dialog box. How do I accomplish this?

I have an FBML tab on my facebook fan page. In the content of that tab, I would like an image to function as a share button.

[By following these](http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/fbml-how-to-add-a-share-button-to-your-facebook-fan-page/) directions, I can customize a share button, but the image itself that the user clicks on is not customizable. I want to be able to provide my own image, not use the silver share button provided by facebook.

[By following these alternative directions](http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-create-your-one-facebook-share-url/) I can use my own image. Perfect! Except on thing... Share.php opens as a *page* instead of as a javascript dialog. So when the user completes the dialog, it closes the whole page!

[Here's what it looks like right now.](https://www.facebook.com/gift.of.sleep?sk=app_4949752878) Sorry, you have to click "Like" to see the share image. When you click the image, the share page opens, but I just want the ajax dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do what you want using the facebook feed dialogs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

this is the javascript that you will have to bind to your onClick event of your link:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: "Name",
        link: "http:\\www.facebook.com\pages\@\page_id_here",
        picture: "http:\\path\to\image\file.jpg",
        caption: "Caption",
        description: "Description",
        message: "Message" 
    },
    function(response) {                                    
        //callback function
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found that simply using my second method with target=_blank is "good enough" for now, but I'd feel like a jerk if I didn't at least give your method a shot since you took the time to answer. I appreciate that. I'm going to try it out later this week when I have a little more time.